# Wordpress - Adding Dimension to WPRocket Placeholder Doesn't Work

Tags: php, wordpress, lazy-loading

I am trying to set custom lazyload placeholder for WP Rocket. It works fine but when I try to set the size, it doesnt set it, instead it sets its size to original image where lazyload takes place.

My code;

```
add_filter( 'rocket_lazyload_placeholder', function( $placeholder ) {
    $placeholder = get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/images/loader.svg';
return $placeholder;
}, 64, 64 );
```

How WP Rocket handles it;

```
/**
 * Returns the placeholder for the src attribute
 *
 * @since 1.2
 *
 * @param int $width  Width of the placeholder image. Default 0.
 * @param int $height Height of the placeholder image. Default 0.
 * @return string
 */
public function getPlaceholder( $width = 0, $height = 0 ) {
    $width  = 0 === $width ? 0 : absint( $width );
    $height = 0 === $height ? 0 : absint( $height );

    $placeholder = str_replace( ' ', '%20', "data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 $width $height'%3E%3C/svg%3E" );
    /**
     * Filter the image lazyLoad placeholder on src attribute
     *
     * @since 1.1
     *
     * @param string $placeholder Placeholder that will be printed.
     * @param int    $width Placeholder width.
     * @param int    $height Placeholder height.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'rocket_lazyload_placeholder', $placeholder, $width, $height );
}
```

Example output;

```
<img fetchpriority="high" decoding="async" width="300" height="215" src="#LOADER_URL#" class="attachment-300x215 size-300x215 wp-post-image" alt="" data-lazy-src="##ACTUAL_IMAGE##">
```

Until the actual Image loaded I need width and height to be 64px.

Is there anything I am missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Those `64, 64` you are passing to `add_filter` are the `$priority` and `$accepted_args` parameters of that function, they have nothing to do with any image sizes.

Comment: The width and height the `getPlaceholder` function sets, are for the SVG that gets used as the placeholder image - it is only the part in `src="#LOADER_URL#"`, that gets replaced by this SVG image encoded as a data URI. The `width="300" height="215"` you are getting on the `img` element itself, don't have anything to do with this function in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CBroe, yes you are right I noticed this way later after posting this question. Unfortunately I couldn't find any way to set lazy loaders size :( It always sets images size even though the SVG has size attributes inside

Comment: `<img width="300" height="215"` - that is what determines the size of the image. The SVG gets put into the `src` attribute, encoded as a data URI - but if the SVG dimensions differ, that will simply mean it will get scaled. You would have get the the width and height of the img element itself changed here - and then you probably also need a mechanism, to set the _correct_ width and height, after the image was lazy-loaded ... because I doubt that will happen automatically.